# How to get exactly the same result of timeval with C++11 chrono

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, gettimeofday

In my C++ project, there is a very old function, which used the system function of Linux to do some calculation about time.

Here is a picec of code:

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
uint32_t seqId = (tv.tv_sec % 86400)*10000 + tv.tv_usec / 100;
```

`* 10000` and `/ 100` are not wrong, because this piece of code is about to generate a seqId.

Now, I'm trying to use `std::chrono` of C++11 to replace it. Here is my code:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration duration_since_midnight() {
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::time_t tnow = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(now);
    tm *date = std::localtime(&tnow);
    date->tm_hour = 0;
    date->tm_min = 0;
    date->tm_sec = 0;
    auto midnight = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(date));
    return now - midnight;
}
auto res = duration_since_midnight();
auto sec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(res);
auto mil = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(res - sec);
std::cout << sec.count() * 10000 + mil.count() << std::endl;
```

However, the result is always kind of wrong. For example, the old version may give me `360681491` but my version would give me `360680149`. You see they are not exactly the same.

I don't know why. Or it's not possible to do so with `std::chrono`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to stick to the duration types that the library provides. You can define your own that has the representation that you need:

```
using tenthmillis = duration<long, ratio<1,10000>>;
```

Then you can follow up with the following calculation.

```
auto now = high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
auto oneDay = duration_cast<tenthmillis>(days{1});
auto sinceMidnight = duration_cast<tenthmillis>(now) % oneDay.count();

cout << sinceMidnight.count();
```

Note: Add namespace qualifications as required yourself.

[Update: Instead of `high_resolution_clock`, choose a clock that uses `gettimeofday` in its implementation to get results that are comparable to your `gettimeofday` implementation.]

Comment: It's not compilable. `now` is a time_point, which can't be converted to a `duration` immediately, right? So I used `(std::chrono::time_point_cast<tenthmillis>(now).time_since_epoch() % oneDay).count();`.

Comment: If I'm right, could you please update your answer later?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I could come up with an even simpler procedure.

Comment: Just one nitpick:  `high_resolution_clock` doesn't necessarily have an epoch that starts on a day boundary.  With gcc it does, but nowhere else.  `system_clock` is the right tool for this job.

Comment: @HowardHinnant The solution is system-dependent anyway. The requirement is "produce the same result that `gettimeofday` gives", so OP has to check which of the clocks uses `gettimeofday` or an equivalent behind the scenes.

Comment: `gettimeofday` returns the number of seconds and microseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  In C++11/14/17 the epoch of `system_clock` is unspecified, but all implementations use the same epoch as `gettimeofday`.  In C++20 this existing practice is standardized:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1  In all versions of C++, the epoch of `high_resolution_clock` is unspecified, and different implementations have different epochs. Linux/gcc is the only implementation that makes `high_resolution_clock` a type alias for `system_clock`. `system_clock` is the right tool for this job.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I'm not questioning your expertise. Note though that (as far as I understood the question) "since midnight" is just a red herring. "Same as `gettimeofday`" is the important part, hence, whichever clock uses that behind the scenes is the right tool for this particular job.